# Django ImageField in forms not uploading, works from admin but not from form

Tags: django, forms

So, I have a system where users can either choose from an already existing image gallery, or upload a new image to be processed and saved.

First off, the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and our form

```
class PostForm(BaseModelForm):
    new_image = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    def clean(self):

        return self.cleaned_data

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('title','text', 'image', 'new_image', description')

    help_texts = {
       'new_image': _('either upload a new image, or choose from the gallery')
    }
```

so then our view where it gets processed

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.slug=slugify(post.title)
            if form.cleaned_data.get('new_image'):
                image = Image(title=post.title, description=post.description, image = request.FILES['new_image'])
                image.save()
                post.image = image


            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Now what this should be doing is creating a new image object out of the form field, then saving it to the foreignkey constraint on the post model.  But what it does is nothing, the post uploads fine with a blank image field, and the image never gets created.  This makes me think the if statement for 'new_image' is resolving to False but I can't figure out why it would do that.

Also, for conventions sake, should this be happening in the form class or the view class?

also, my image model

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/', default =     'images/None/no-img.jpg')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to change

```
form = PostForm(request.POST)
```

to:

```
form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

you need to add request.FILES in order to upload the file as per the documentation

[Django Documentation: File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/)

You may want to use pre-save/post-save signals to create the new image save when a post/image is saved via the form to the Image model.

---

You need to add your Image model to this example. Looking at how you are saving the image information via the form, Im going to assume you aren't using the

```
ImageField()
```

model on your Image Model. Only way to tell is you showing that model as well.

[Django Documentation: Model Field Reference: ImageField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)

This field is how Django uploads images through forms.

You may need to add two forms to your view one for the post and the other for the new image upload.

Im still learning this myself so you can look on here and find some assistance with this.

Comment: This is helpful!  Ive added the image model in

Comment: can you up my post. Thank you.

Comment: I deleted my other post since it didn't help and I don't want anyone to use it since it isn't helpful.

Comment: Thats okay, you're very helpful.  I'm thinking of implementing an ImageForm, and coming back to this.

Comment: Im having a similar issue with trying to process my image upload form with two forms on one page. My image files aren't being uploaded as well. But Im glad I could help.

Comment: Hey, if your still struggling check the answer I posted.  Best of luck :)

Answer (score 7):

The form template need this: enctype="multipart/form-data", I added that and suddenly we have functional image processing!

Comment: For anyone in the future who runs into this, he's referring to this line in templates:
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'something' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: This saved me, whenever there is an ImageField/FileField we need to add this tag to the form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Thanks!